# How to call JSON RPC method inside controller on Lambda AWS project

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, json-rpc

I need an help. My problem is making api with JSON RPC 2.0 on .net core 2.0 project.
So, i've installed this https://github.com/edjCase/JsonRpc plugin.
And set ItemsController like this:

```
namespace AWSTestLambda.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/v1/[Controller]")]
    public class ItemsController : RpcController
    {
        public String Test(int id)
        {
            return "testing";
        }
    }
}
```

So, i call the method with postman on local like this (on local machine):

URL set on POST: `http://localhost:55241/api/Items`

And like body set (raw):

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "Test",
    "params": {
        "id": 1234
    },
    "id": ""
}
```

The response is:

```
{
    "id": "",
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32601,
        "message": "No methods matched request.",
        "data": null
    }
}
```

How can solve this problem ? I don't know like call the method inside the controller.
Thanks all.

Comment: Try using the address `http://localhost:55241/api/v1/Items/Test` because your controllers route is `api/v1/Items` and your calling the `Test` method on it

Comment: @MindSwipe excuse me but, the json rpc not need it to set controller on url to call, right ? Or i should add the name controller also in the url to call and also into "method" proprertie when i call

Comment: You're not calling the controller directly. You're initiating a get request to a URI. And your controller Method `Test` has the URI `http://localhost:55241/api/v1/Items/Test` and because it's a get request the entire URI will look like this: `http://localhost:55241/api/v1/Items/Test?id=1234`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change post url to **http://localhost:55241/api/v1/Items**.
You have set yout route [Route("api/v1/[Controller]")] but you are calling **http://localhost:55241/api/Items**.